# Subquotients of Module

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

In Rotman's book on homological algebra (page 625), he says that if you have modules $Y\subset X\subset Z$ with $X/Y=Z$ then $Y=0$ and $X=Z$. It's not clear what he means by $X/Y=Z$ in the first place, but I can only assume he means isomorphic, although there then seems to be fairly easy counter-examples: $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{4N}}\subset \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{2N}}\subset \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$, where for example $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{2N}}=\{(0,x_{1},0,x_{2},0,..): x_{i}\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, since $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{2N}}/\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{4N}}=\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ via a bijection between $\mathbb{2N}\setminus\mathbb{4N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Can anyone correct me, or is this indeed a mistake?

Comment: You mean $Y/X$?

Comment: Yeah, just realised that, thanks.

Comment: At some point, you have to play fast and loose between equality and isomorphism or you'll drive yourself crazy worrying about the distinction.  Did he make a blanket assumption anywhere that things are always finitely generated?

Comment: Yeah I know, the statement just seemed obviously wrong when talking about isomorphism. The chapter is on spectral sequences and I've no reason to assume any assumption of modules being finitely generated is made, although I agree if that were the case everything would probably be ok.

Answer (score 1):

What Rotman wants to prove is that if $E^r= E^{r+1}$ in a spectral sequence, then $Z^{r+1} = Z^r$ and $B^{r+1} = B^r$. Remember that $E^{r+1}$ is computed as the homology of $E^r$ with respect to a differential. What Rotman is saying here is:  the differential is zero iff $E^r=E^{r+1}$, iff the cycles (resp. boundaries) at stage $r$ are the same as those at stage $r+1$.

Indeed, note that if $E^r=E^{r+1}$ then there is no differential, so the cycles are equal, and now you want to prove that if $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ and the natural map $C/B \to C/A$ is an isomorphism, then $A=B$. The converse is obvious.

Comment: The thing is though, does $E^{r}=E^{r+1}$ imply there is no differential? The converse is obvious, but by some coincidence when you compute the homologies you may get back the same modules even if the differentials are non-zero.

Comment: @MadChickenMan No. If the canonical map $C\to H(C)$ is an isomorphism, then necessarily there is no differential.

Comment: Maybe this is part of my confusion then, because I don't know what this canonical map is, could you explain?

Comment: @MadChickenMan Well, I am somewhat misspeaking when I say "canonical". What I mean is that to compute $H(C)$ you compute, first, $\ker d$, and then quotient out, and both these maps are isomorphisms. The statement "$E^r = H(E^r,d^r) = E^{r+1}$"  is equivalent to $\ker d=0$. I just think Rotman is making things more confusing by bringing up formulas like $X/Y=Z$.